# Dispatch group notify to reload tableview

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have a function that is called when tableview is pulled down to reload.
In the function, I need to reload tableview after 3 alamofire requests, but its not working properly...

```
self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
if let URL = URL(string: "fetch1", relativeTo: Property.baseURL){
    fetchGroup.enter()
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": Property.shared.token,
        "content-type": "application/json"
    ]

    Property.alamofireManager.request(URL, headers: headers).responseJSON{ response in
        //Manage json
        print("LEAVE 1")
        self.fetchGroup.leave()
    }
}

if let URL = URL(string: "fetch2", relativeTo: Property.baseURL){
    fetchGroup.enter()
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": Property.shared.token,
        "content-type": "application/json"
    ]

    Property.alamofireManager.request(URL, headers: headers).responseJSON{ response in
        //Manage json
        print("LEAVE 2")
        self.fetchGroup.leave()
    }
}

if let URL = URL(string: "fetch3", relativeTo: Property.baseURL){
    fetchGroup.enter()
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": Property.shared.token,
        "content-type": "application/json"
    ]

    Property.alamofireManager.request(URL, headers: headers).responseJSON{ response in
        //Manage json
        print("LEAVE 3")
        self.fetchGroup.leave()
    }
}

fetchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
    print("Going to Refresh")
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Basically what happens in above code is somehow the program reached `self.tableview.reloadData()` in notify, and also it does not print out "Going to Refresh". I was wondering if i were reloading the tableview from different function so i tried commenting out `self.tableView.reloadData()` but it was the only place where it reloads the tableview. Does anyone have any idea why the code is not working as intended?

Right now, it shows 
"LEAVE 2"
"LEAVE 3"
but it does not show "LEAVE 1". It just directly goes to reload without waiting for "LEAVE 1"

Comment: Are you sure that all the `leave` statements are actually being reached?

Comment: Yes, i've checked multiple times already ..

Comment: Also get rid of the `else` statements... there is nothing to do if the `URL` creation fails because you won't have `enter`ed in that case

Comment: @BallpointBen In the absence of other clues, that would be my suspect as to why the dispatch group isn't working as expected. If one `if let` statement returns a value and the other one returns `nil`, you'll enter and then immediately leave the group, so the `notify` and subsequent table reload will fire well before any of your network accesses occur.

Comment: Add a breakpoint where you do `reloadData` and see if you're really hitting that line. Bottom line, it's impossible to hit that line and not encounter the `print` statement, so there's something else going on.

Comment: Having said that, there is a problem in this code. Your `if` statements `enter` the group _inside_ the `if` block and `leave` in the Alamofire completion block. But you have an `else` clause for each of these that `leave` the group without ever entering it. You should either remove those `else` clauses or move the `enter` _before_ their respective `if` statements. Admittedly, this wouldn't explain the behavior you describe, but nevertheless is a problem you should fix.

Comment: Yes, I fixed them already... hmm i dont understand giving so much headache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How often your code is being executed? I imagine a situation like that:

1. User scrolls Table.
2. You invoke requests, multiple 'enter' calls are being invoked.
3. User scrolls again, #2 is called again, before actual requests are finished.

Depending on how you handle such case, the user may experience weird behavior.

Comment: yes that is what i realized too. that is executed everytime when user pull down the table... I am thinking to fix this part as well. However, this fetchGroupNotify is triggered before all the leave() are called

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to have same count of enter and leave, and be sure that when you enter you leave for dispatch group.

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
dispatchGroup.enter()
custom_function_1 { dispatchGroup.leave() }

dispatchGroup.enter()
custom_function_2 { dispatchGroup.leave() }

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("Completed")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, it wasnt calling reload tableview. While it is editting dataset, tableview was trying to reuse a cell because of tableview bounce to next cell.